# How to organizine a dictionary within tuples in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I need to apply a transformation to my data in order to organize it in a dictionary within tuples

my original data structure is :

```
my_data = [("description text", 'yes'), ("description text", 'no'), ("description text", 'no'), ("description text", 'no')]
```

And this is what I have been trying to do, but unfortunately I have not succeeded.

```
 my_data=[]
    
    with open("data/My_DF.csv", encoding="utf-8") as my_df:
        rd = csv.DictReader(my_df)
        for d in rd:
            my_data.append((d["description"],d["classification"]))
            
def transform_dic(have_data):
    data_is_ready = []
    for i in have_data:
        dic = {}
        dic[i[1]] = i[1]
        data_is_ready.append(("description", dic, dic[i[1]]))
    return data_is_ready

my_data =  transform_dic(my_data)
```

The end result I need is the following:

```
final_data = [
 ({'description': description text}, 'yes'),
 ({'description': description text}, 'no'),
 ({'description': description text}, 'no'),
 ({'description': description text}, 'no')
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_data = [("description text", 'yes'), ("description text", 'no'),
           ("description text", 'no'), ("description text", 'no')]
my_data = [({'description':item0}, item1) for item0, item1 in my_data]
print(my_data)
```

output

```
[({'description': 'description text'}, 'yes'), ({'description': 'description text'}, 'no'), 
 ({'description': 'description text'}, 'no'), ({'description': 'description text'}, 'no')]
```